# TensorFlow custom operation: Thread safety of output tensor

Tags: c++, multithreading, tensorflow

I have a custom operation for TensorFlow which benefits from doing a certain computation in parallel.
However, one user reported a [crash](https://github.com/githubharald/CTCWordBeamSearch/issues/8) when using this parallel computation (on my computer everything works fine).

- Is there anything I have to take care in the Compute method when working with threads?
- Is reading/writing tensors already thread-safe or do I have to take care?
- Especially, do I have to synchronize my threads when writing to the output tensor? See simplified code snippet below.

```
    void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override 
    {
        // output tensor
        Tensor* outputTensor = nullptr;
        OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, TensorShape({maxI, maxJ}), &outputTensor));
        auto outputMapped = outputTensor->tensor();

        // do some computations for index (i, j) and write result to index (i, j) of output tensor
        // do this for each (i, j) combination
        outputMapped(i, j) = result; 

        // computing the result for each index (i, j) in parallel would speed up the computation
        // Question: is it allowed to write to outputMapped(i, j) from different threads without synchronization?
    }
```

This is the relevant code:

- [Compute(...) method: output tensor](https://github.com/githubharald/CTCWordBeamSearch/blob/master/cpp/src/TFWordBeamSearch.cpp#L204)
- [Start parallel work](https://github.com/githubharald/CTCWordBeamSearch/blob/master/cpp/src/TFWordBeamSearch.cpp#L215)
- [Write to output tensor from each thread in parallel](https://github.com/githubharald/CTCWordBeamSearch/blob/master/cpp/src/TFWordBeamSearch.cpp#L125)

I looked through the [TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op), but it only mentions that TF itself may call Compute(...) in parallel. But I could not find any information about thread-safety of the tensors. Does anyone have more information about this?